# Could not determine size of CHARACTER while installing openmpi

Tags: openmpi

I am trying to install openmpi on Amazon ec2 instance. I have uninstalled the openmpi installations present in the system using -

```
yum remove -y  openmpi.x86_64 openmpi-devel.x86_64
```

This removes `2.1.1-1.31.amzn1` version of openmpi and openmpi devel.

I have downloaded the tar file from official openmpi [site](https://www.open-mpi.org/software/ompi/v3.0/). When I try running configure, I get the following error -

```
checking if C and Fortran are link compatible... yes
checking to see if Fortran compiler likes the C++ exception flags... skipped (no C++ exceptions flags)
checking to see if mpifort compiler needs additional linker flags... none
checking if Fortran compiler supports CHARACTER... yes
checking size of Fortran CHARACTER... configure: WARNING: Could not determine size of CHARACTER
configure: WARNING: See config.log for details
configure: error: Cannot continue
```

Errors in config.log file -

`configure:37098: $? = 0
configure:37111: result: yes
configure:37146: checking size of Fortran CHARACTER
configure:37214: /usr/lib/a-4.2.0-py-3.5.3-dl-gpu-full/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc -DNDEBUG -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -pipe -finline-functions -fno-strict-aliasing -I. -c conftest.c
configure:37221: $? = 0
configure:37231: gfortran   conftestf.f90 conftest.o -o conftest -Wl,-O2 -Wl,--sort-common -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now
/usr/bin/ld: conftest.o: unrecognized relocation (0x29) in section .text'
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:37238: $? = 1
configure:37259: here is the Fortran program:
program fsize`

I have tried with `./configure —disable-fortran` as well but I am getting the same error.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: In order to disable Fortran, the option is `--disable-mpi-fortran`

Comment: Open MPI **does** require a C++ compiler, is `g++` installed ?

Comment: yes, GCC was installed. I was using the wrong flag using --disable-mpi-fortran worked.

Comment: You seem to be using different compilers for c and fortan...